# ArgoCD Access via CLI not accesible

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, argo

I am trying this command

```bash
argocd login $(kubectl get ingress argocd-server-ingress -n argocd -o jsonpath='{.spec.rules[0].host}') --username admin --password $(kubectl -n argocd get secret  argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d; echo) --insecure
```

I get this error:

> dial tcp IP_ADDRESS operation was canceled

This is my ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: argocd-server-ingress
    namespace: argocd
    annotations:
      custom.nginx.org/backend: https
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 600m
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-http-version: '1.1'
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
  spec:
    tls: 
    - hosts:
      - example.com
      secretName: secret
    rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: argocd-server
              port:
                name: http
```

I was able to login ArgoCD CLI when I change the default argo-cd service to type LoadBalancer but this is not viable for the production environment and makes sense to create an ingress record for the custom hostname. So, why can I not log in to CLI through ingress?

Answer (score 0):

hmm odd, it should work, I tried your command got an "broken pipe" error first but then after I ran it again it work no problem :(